# gfortran - assign string to parameter

Tags: fortran, gfortran

[NOTE: contains repetition of previous question but posted separately as separate issues]

I am compiling a program which is known to compile with ifort using gfortran. However the compiler fails on the line

```
PARAMETER (POS='^')
```

with the compile error:

```
conv_prof.mac:9.21:
    Included at conv_prof.f:811:

      PARAMETER (POS='^')                                               
                 1
Error: Can't convert CHARACTER(1) to REAL(4) at (1)
make: *** [conv_prof.o] Error 1
```

As it turns out the POS parameter is not used (it is likely a legacy parameter) so I may simply uncomment this line to compile, but I would like to know if anyone might have any idea why this is an issue in gfortran and not ifort?

Cheers,

Derek

Answer (score 3):

The Intel compiler is the descendant of a long line of Fortran compilers.  Its ancestors implemented all sorts of non-standard behaviour and, in the true spirit of Fortran, the latest versions of the compiler ought to compile the most ancient codes.  You can often tell `ifort` to warn of non-standard features in your codes by judicious use of compiler flags.

gfortran, on the other hand, does not (by default) accept much in the way of non-standard syntax, other than those forms of non-standard syntax which have been so widely used that many unsuspecting programmers think that they are standard forms (eg `real*4` and the like).

Your snippet looks to me to come from the days prior to FORTRAN77 when the language didn't really acknowledge the existence of such new-fangled ideas as non-numeric variables.  In this case I recommend that you follow gfortran in disallowing this code, rather than Intel Fortran.

Comment: Thank you, that's good to know. I was operating on the assumption that the intel compilers were more 'conforming'. I will report this back to the original authors of the code. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

The specific extension here is that ifort allows a program to "assign" a character value into a real object.  Perhaps it was intended to use this extension - but a more likely explanation is that a type declaration statement for the parameter `pos` is missing prior to the PARAMETER statement.

Technically I don't think the standard requires a diagnostic in this case (this isn't a violation of the syntax rules or constraints of the standard - it is a violation of the requirements placed on the program in the body text), but you'll get a diagnostic from ifort if you turn on standards checking (`/stand` or `-stand`, depending on your platform).